# Frobenius mophism, Exercise 7.3 R of Ravi Vakil's book on algebraic geometry

Tags: algebraic-geometry, commutative-algebra

I am a geometry person and got stuck in Exercise 7.3.R which is about Frobenius morphism.

Suppose $p$ is a prime and $r \in \mathbb{Z}^+$. Let $q=p^r$ and $k=\mathbb{F}_q$. Define $\phi :k[x_1,\dots,x_n] \rightarrow k[x_1,\dots,x_n]$ by $\phi(x_i)=x_i^p$ for each $i$, and let $F:\mathbb{A}_k^n \rightarrow \mathbb{A}_k^n$ be the map of schemes corresponding to $\phi$.

(a) Show that $F^r$ is the identity on the level of sets, but is not the identity morphism.

(b) Show that $F$ is a bijection, but is not an isomophism of schemes.

(c) If $K=\bar{F}_p$, show that the morphism $F:\mathbb{A}_K^n \rightarrow \mathbb{A}_K^n$ of $K$-schemes corresponding to $x_i \rightarrow x_i^p$ is a bijection, but no power of $F$ is the identity on the level of sets!

For (a) and (b), I only know the solution when $n=1$ since $k[x]$ is a PID which makes it very easy. But I got stuck when $n>1$.

Comment: $k[x_1, \dots, x_n]$ is a UFD. Does that help?

Comment: My guess is that your proof for (a) and (b) doesn't really need the PID bit. It all should boil down to the fact that with coefficients in $\mathbf{F}_q$ one has $f(x_1^q, \dots, x_n^q) = f(x_1, \dots, x_n)^q$. For (c), I think it's important that $\overline{\mathbf{F}}_p$ is the union of the $\mathbf{F}_q$.

Comment: Thank you @Hoot, I could answer (a) and (b) from your hints.

Comment: I am really confused about these exercise by Vakil, since he does not state what happens with constants. Are they also raised to powers or are they fixed? This gives rise to different morphisms, especially if $k$ is not perfect (of course its perfect in our case).

Comment: I believe the constants are fixed. I don't see why he would word it the way he does otherwise. And in (c) he explicitly says "of $K$-schemes".

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For $c)$, notice that surjections are stable under base change, i.e. $F: \mathbb A_K^n \to \mathbb A_K^n$ is a surjection as the base change of of $F: \mathbb A_k^n \to \mathbb A_k^n$. For injectivity, let $F(\mathfrak p) = F(\mathfrak q)$ for two primes in $K[x_1, \dotsc, x_n]$. In general we have $\phi(\phi^{-1}(A))=A \cap \operatorname{image}(\phi)$ for any subset $A$, i.e. we deduce

$$\mathfrak p \cap K[x_1^p, \dotsc, x_n^p] = \mathfrak q \cap K[x_1^p, \dotsc, x_n^p].$$

From this, you can easily deduce $\mathfrak p = \mathfrak q$: Let $f \in \mathfrak p$. Then $f^p \in \mathfrak p \cap K[x_1^p, \dotsc, x_n^p] = \mathfrak q \cap K[x_1^p, \dotsc, x_n^p] \subset \mathfrak q$, hence $f \in \mathfrak q$, since it is a prime ideal.

Thus we have shown hat $F$ is a bijection on the level of sets. But no power is the identity map:

Let $r > 0$ and $a \in K \setminus \mathbb F_{p^r}$. $(\phi^r)^{-1}((x_1-a))=(x_1-a^{p^r})$, i.e. the prime ideal $(x_1-a)$ is mapped by $F^r$ to $(x_1-a^{p^r})$, which is not the same, since $a \neq a^{p^r}$. Hence $F^r$ is not the identity map.

Answer (score 3):

Thanks to the hints by Hoot, I try to answer (a) and (b) by the following,

We have $\phi^r(f(x_i))=f(x_i^{q})=f(x_i)^q$, so it is obvious that for every prime ideal $P \subset k[x_1,\cdots,x_n]$, $\phi^r(P) \subset P$, so $P \subset (\phi^r)^{-1}(P)$. Now we show that $(\phi^r)^{-1}(P) \subset P$, which will show that $F^r$ is identity.

For $f\in (\phi^r)^{-1}(P)$, which means $\phi^r(f(x_i))=f(x_i^{q})=f(x_i)^q \in P$, so $f \in P$ since $P$ is a prime ideal.

$F^r$ is not the identity morphism since $\phi^r$ is not identity homomophism.

(b) follows from (a).